# Ambiguous call to overloaded function (with a variable argument list)

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

I have the following code:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        BOOL GetBar(char** ptr);
    private:
        BOOL GetBar(char** ptr, ...);
};

Foo* aFoo = ...;
char* aPtr = ...;

BOOL res = aFoo->GetBar(&aPtr);//error C2668
```

which generates the following error:

```
error C2668: 'Foo::GetBar' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
        Foo.h: could be 'BOOL Foo::GetBar(char **,...)'
        Foo.h: or 'BOOL Foo::GetBar(char **)'
        while trying to match the argument list '(char **)'
```

Is there a way to fix this error without renaming one of the GetBar functions?

(Visual Studio 2005)

Comment: Throw out the first one and code the `va_args` you're using for the second to account for no parameters.

Comment: Variadic means you can pass zero as well.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't test for no args? You do `va_start(a_va_list, ptr)`, then `va_arg(a_va_list, int-or-whatever)`, and if `int-or-whatever` is not there you're in undefined behavior country.

Comment: I guess I could pass `NULL` as a magic number for the `...`.

Comment: `BOOL (Foo::*gb)(char**ptr) = &Foo::GetBar; BOOL res = aFoo->*gb(&aPtr);`